Missing Library Functions and Unresolved Symbols During Linking on Ubuntu 23.10 (Mantic)
I am trying to install R from source for Ubuntu 23.10 machine, since I couldn't just use the existing repo as it was not for "Mantic". I followed the R documentation but I keep encountering an error while running the "make" command.
The error is :
make[3]: Entering directory '/home/gcu-gro/Downloads/R-4.4.0/src/unix'
make[3]: 'libunix.a' is up to date.
make[3]: Leaving directory '/home/gcu-gro/Downloads/R-4.4.0/src/unix'
make[3]: Entering directory '/home/gcu-gro/Downloads/R-4.4.0/src/unix'
gcc -I. -I../../src/include -I../../src/include  -I/usr/local/include -DHAVE_CONFIG_H    -g -O2  -L/usr/local/lib -DR_HOME='"/home/gcu-gro/Downloads/R-4.4.0"' \ -o Rscript ./Rscript.c
make[3]: Leaving directory '/home/gcu-gro/Downloads/R-4.4.0/src/unix'
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/gcu-gro/Downloads/R-4.4.0/src/unix'
make[2]: Entering directory '/home/gcu-gro/Downloads/R-4.4.0/src/main'
make[3]: Entering directory '/home/gcu-gro/Downloads/R-4.4.0/src/main'
make[4]: Entering directory '/home/gcu-gro/Downloads/R-4.4.0/src/main'
/home/gcu-gro/Downloads/R-4.4.0/lib/libR.so is unchanged
make[4]: Leaving directory '/home/gcu-gro/Downloads/R-4.4.0/src/main'
make[3]: Leaving directory '/home/gcu-gro/Downloads/R-4.4.0/src/main'
make[3]: Entering directory '/home/gcu-gro/Downloads/R-4.4.0/src/main'
gcc -Wl,--export-dynamic -fopenmp  -L"../../lib" -L/usr/local/lib -o R.bin Rmain.o  -lR 
/usr/bin/ld: ../../lib/libR.so: undefined reference to `ucol_setAttribute_73'
/usr/bin/ld: ../../lib/libR.so: undefined reference to `ucol_close_73'
/usr/bin/ld: ../../lib/libR.so: undefined reference to `libiconv'
/usr/bin/ld: ../../lib/libR.so: undefined reference to `ucol_open_73'
/usr/bin/ld: ../../lib/libR.so: undefined reference to `uiter_setUTF8_73'
/usr/bin/ld: ../../lib/libR.so: undefined reference to `libiconv_close'
/usr/bin/ld: ../../lib/libR.so: undefined reference to `ucol_getLocaleByType_73'
/usr/bin/ld: ../../lib/libR.so: undefined reference to `_libiconv_version'
/usr/bin/ld: ../../lib/libR.so: undefined reference to `ucol_setStrength_73'
/usr/bin/ld: ../../lib/libR.so: undefined reference to `libiconv_open'
/usr/bin/ld: ../../lib/libR.so: undefined reference to `u_versionToString_73'
/usr/bin/ld: ../../lib/libR.so: undefined reference to `ucol_strcollIter_73'
/usr/bin/ld: ../../lib/libR.so: undefined reference to `uloc_setDefault_73'
/usr/bin/ld: ../../lib/libR.so: undefined reference to `u_getVersion_73'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[3]: *** [Makefile:150: R.bin] Error 1
make[3]: Leaving directory '/home/gcu-gro/Downloads/R-4.4.0/src/main'
make[2]: *** [Makefile:141: R] Error 2
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/gcu-gro/Downloads/R-4.4.0/src/main'
make[1]: *** [Makefile:28: R] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/gcu-gro/Downloads/R-4.4.0/src'
make: *** [Makefile:62: R] Error 1`


I am completely new to Linux and R, so it would be great if someone could help me.

Ubuntu has the iconv functionality in glibc. You therefore don't need to install GNU libiconv on Ubuntu.
